# How to use Facebook SDK in unity to start Facebook Ads to advertise game?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-ads-api

1. Do I need Facebook sdk to start advertising my game in  Facebook Ads manager? (I have integrated Firebase inside the game)
2. How to properly integrate Facebook SDK to manage own ads of game in Facebook Ads Manager. (It will be really helpful for beginner developers to advertise own game)
3. What do we need to write inside code to track in facebook ads manager?

If someone know this problem can you make step by step guide. :)

Actually I didn't tried Facebook SDK but want to know if I need it to advertise in Facebook ads manager.